# SQLite Replace Straight Quotes with Curly Quotes

Tags: sqlite, typography, ghost-blog

I run a Ghost blog and I want to find and replace all my single and double quotes into "curly quotes," (see [here](http://practicaltypography.com/straight-and-curly-quotes.html)) but I don't know SQLite very well. So far, I have come up with this:

```
update posts set markdown = replace(markdown, '""', '“');
```

The above command replaces all my double quotes to opening curly quotes (ALT+0147). Then I tried running the same command, but substituting for the closing quote (ALT+0148), like so:

```
update posts set markdown = replace(markdown, '“', '”');
```

Which basically replaces all the opening curly quotes with closing quotes. And that is where I am stuck. I'm not sure how to make an exception in sqlite, so that it only replaces the quotes that have text after them. Additionally, I haven't considered cases, where I want my straight quotes to stay the same, such as in the HTML links, as pointed out in the comments.

**Update: It Works**

Thanks to an answer, I have found a solution, which in my case has worked perfectly! Take note that I used the *DB Browser for SQLite* to make changes to my database -

```
update posts set markdown = replace(markdown, ' "', ' “');
update posts set markdown = replace(markdown, '." ', '.” ');
update posts set markdown = replace(markdown, '" ', '” ');
```

The above two commands have replaced all the opening double quotes with curly quotes, and the same for the closing quotes. All that's now left to do is, as stated in the answer below, cover all the possibilities, where such quotes may appear. Same goes for the single quotes, as so:

```
update posts set markdown = replace(markdown, ' ''', ' ‘');
update posts set markdown = replace(markdown, '.'' ', '.’ ');
update posts set markdown = replace(markdown, ''' ', '’ ');
```

And for all the inbetween apostrophes:

```
update posts set markdown = replace(markdown, '''', '’');
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], i.e. a `.dump` of a suitably tailored toy database.

Comment: Make sure you have sample input which covers all the cases you want to handle. E.g. string starts and ends with quotes, string contains a quoted word in the middle. String starts with quoted word, then continues. Starts unquoted, then ends with quoted. Combinations of above with two quoted parts. Quoted parts containing spaces....

Comment: Hi @Yunnosch I have exported and uploaded one post from the blog as a .SQL to https://pastebin.com/E1f9waZh

By the way, I use the "DB Browser for SQLite" program to make changes to my databases. I exported it from there.

Comment: Do you want to replace these: `a href="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0166924/"` ? I guess not.

Comment: Otherwise your sample only contains these, which I guess you want to repelace: `What a film. Let me repeat that - "WHAT. A. FILM." David Lynch creates things on drugs.` Are you sure that you do not want to give more examples? Replacing these is so simple that I feel there must be a catch somewhere. Please give more sample input.

Comment: Please show by what you want to replace the opening single quotes, the closing single quotes, the opening double quotes and the closing double quotes. As it is, your question only shows one kind of quotes and it is not even clear whether you consider them opening or closing. By the way the single kind you show is not offered by my keyboard, but that is not relevant, apart from me not knowing what the opposite is.

Comment: Double check the list of cases I made in my first comment. I will only provide solution for sample input you provide, currently the only example I can find in your sample input is "quoted part contains only embedded space; is within other text; separated by space". This single example has an obvious solution, but I bet you want more cases covered. I cannot find a single example for single quotes within markdown; assuming that you do not want to replace `''`, which obviously represents a single `'` to be rendered.

Comment: Hi @Yunnosch, sorry if I'm being unclear. That was just one post of the many, and my aim was to make my site typographically beautiful, by replacing all the double and single quotes, such as the `"WHAT.
 A. FILM."` with curly quotes. You can see an example [here](http://practicaltypography.com/straight-and-curly-quotes.html). And nope, I haven't considered the HTML double quotes for links. So I'm at a loss.

Comment: I know that it is only one example, that is why I am asking for more examples. No need for full database entries (though the one you gave is helpful). Just give some more 'I want "these" replaced but"not these", or this last one"'. And please show the quotes you want after replacing, opening and closing.

Comment: @Yunnosch I edited my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145737/discussion-between-yunnosch-and-nick).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite (in the base version I know) is not very powerful in text manipulation. And even with things like sed, awk or perl it would probably not be easy to get a single replacement doing what OP wants.

I will provide some pure SQLite recipes, which need to be extended and combined to cover all desired cases (and not the undesired cases).
Finding and covering all cases is admittedly a bit tedious. But this is the best I can think of within SQLite. I am happy to upvote any simpler, more powerful answer.
You need to apply those recipes you like to your database.
It should also be easy to extend them to cover cases I have not thought of.

I recommend to first try the effect of each of them by only using the bare recipe, that will just show the "markdown" column in changed form. Only if you like its effect on all your entries, you should apply it, using the "update/set" thing. (I am relying on you being able to do that, your quote of your own attempt looks good.)

Just to explain; applying recipe 1 and 2 will cover the one example I spotted in your sample input, the "What. A. FILM.".
In chat you have (rather flatteringly, thanks) indicated that the other recipes are "reading your mind". Spotting the pattern and extending it to any other example should not be hard.
The one thing I do not see a solution in SQLite for would be 'I repeat " WHAT A FILM " blabla.' The problem are the spaces between the quotes and the quoted text. In sed/perl/awk solutions could check for "first/odd straight quote" and "second/even straight quote" but SQLite cannot easily do that, maybe not at all, ideas are welcome.

1 Replace "space followed by straight double quote" by "space followed by opening curly":
    `select replace(markdown, ' "', ' “') from posts;`

2 Replace "straight double quote followed by space" by "closing curly followed by space":
    `select replace(markdown, '" ', '” ') from posts;`

3 Replace "straight double quote followed by comma" by "closing curly followed by comma":
    `select replace(markdown, '",', '”,') from posts;`

4 Replace "straight double quote followed by semicolon" by "closing curly followed by semicolon":
    `select replace(markdown, '";', '”;') from posts;`

5 Replace "straight double quote followed by fullstop" by "closing curly followed by fullstop":
    `select replace(markdown, '".', '”.') from posts;`

Do the same thing for opening and closing single quotes.
When you start inventing your own replacements, make sure NOT to cover the http link and NOT to cover the `''`, both of which seem obviously not your intended replacement target.

Note, I explicitly admit that these replacements have **failed** on my own machine. But in a chat, OP has tried the simplest version and confirmed that for him they **succeed**. The main difference seems to be that he uses a database browser.
I consider these things therefor "tested successfully", just not on my machine.